# comparing two dimensional list objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure if this is asked before but I couldn't find any help.
I am building a game where I have a two dimentional lists of objects, lets call them `inventory` and `loot`. I need to compare them and see if which ones I already have. Item is a list where we have name, amount and discription.

I was thinking something like

```
ownd = []
for item in self.inv:
    if item[0].name in loot:
        ownd.append(item)
```

However, I should compare item[0] to item[0] in inv but I have a brainblock or something cause I can't figure out how to do this. Could somebody help or push me to right direction. Thanks!!

ps. I know some of you migh see this as a stupid easy question but seriously I am stuck and need help!

EDIT:

More code from the class:

```
class Inventory(object):

    inv = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.ownr = name
        self.loc = "player_data/" + name

    def add_item(self, item, amount):
        for obj in self.inv:
            if obj[0].name == item.name:
                obj[1] = obj[1] + amount
                return 1                       
        self.inv.append([item, amount])
        return 0

    def compare_to_loop(self, loot, amount):
        ownd = []
        for item in self.inv:
            if item[0].name in loot:
                ownd.append(item)
        return ownd
```

Comment: where is the `self` coming from? Cam you post some examples of `inv` and `loot` data structures?

Comment: How do you want the inner lists to be compared? By a certain element or by all of them?

Comment: Noticed I had copied the part incorrectly, it is now corrected. 
WHat I would like to do is to compare the names and pick those items with same name to ownd list

Comment: @Duzzz Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881468/comparing-two-2-dimensional-lists?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685691/trying-to-compare-a-value-to-a-value-in-a-python-two-dimensional-list-but-compa?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to lists inventory and loot and you want to construct a new list owned with all elements that you can find in both lists at the same position?

Then this should work

```
inv = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
loot = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6]
owned = [i for i, l in zip(inv, loot) if i == l]
```

In this example owned should be [3, 4]?